# How check in javascript that a li element has inner ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="sub"><a href="/katalog1/">catalog</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="dir"><a href="">subcatalog</a>               
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">sublink</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">sublink</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">sublink</a></li>
                </ul>               
            </li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="">subcatalog</a></li>
            <li class="dir"><a href="">subcatalog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li class="sub"><a href="">catalog</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">catalog</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">catalog</a></li>
    <li class="sub"><a href="">catalog</a></li>
</ul>

<style>

ul > li.sub:hover > ul{display:block;}
ul > li.sub:hover{
background: #fff url(../../images/arrow1.png) no-repeat 91% center;
border-bottom: 2px solid #e30613;
padding-right: 25px;
}
</style>
```

I use script:

```
$('li.main_menu_top_li').has('ul').addClass('sub');
```

Tell me please how make it on javascript (only javascript)?

Comment: Is the `ul` class you are looking for a child or a parent?

Comment: Please show some HTML

Comment: @mplungjan i add html code, see please

Comment: @metsales  i add html code, see please

Comment: What about `<li class="sub"><a href="">catalog</a></li>` it should NOT have sub. right?

Comment: Where is the `main_menu_top_li` ?

Comment: just out of curiousity, why not use jQuery?

Comment: @metsales becouse it not really on site. i can use only javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One of two ways.

first get the element:

```
var d = document.getElementByClassName("li.main_menu_top_li");
```

Then:

```
if (d.firstChild) {
    // It has at least one
    d.className = d.className + " sub";
}
```

or the hasChildNodes() function:

```
if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
    // It has at least one
    d.className = d.className + " sub";
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to use the `li` elements to test that a `ul` element exists around it, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add the sub class to the LI that has nested ULs under it:

Plain JS

```
var li = document.querySelector('li.main_menu_top_li');
if (li.getElementsByTagName("ul").length>0) li.className+="sub"; 
 // or get the addClass/hasClass from http://snipplr.com/view/3561/
```

jQuery:

```
var li = $('li.main_menu_top_li');
if (li.children('ul').length) li.addClass('sub');
```

If you want to add the class to any UL that is inside an LI then

```
var li = $('li.main_menu_top_li');
li.children('ul').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('sub');
});
```

Comment: Won't querySelector only retrieve the first matched element with class main_menu_top_li?

Comment: Likely, but with a name of main_menu_top_li, I would guess there is only one :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code looks at all LI elements and checks if they have a UL element.  If so, that UL element gets the class 'sub'.  If you want instead for that LI to have the class 'sub', un-comment the commented portions of code and then remove the line underneath each commented line.

Here's the first [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avKf8/6/):

```
//IE 10+ and all other major browsers
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(el);

listItems.forEach(function(el) {
    var childrenList = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children);  

    childrenList.forEach(function(el) {
        if(el.tagName === 'UL') {
            //if(!el.parentNode.classList.contains('sub') {
            if(!el.classList.contains('sub')) {
                //el.parentNode.classList.add('sub')
                el.classList.add('sub');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the second [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avKf8/8/):

```
//IE8+ and all other major browsers, I think
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

var listItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(el);

listItems.forEach(function(el) {
    var childrenList = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children);  

    childrenList.forEach(function(el) {
        if(el.tagName === 'UL') {
            //if(el.parentNode.className === '') {
            if(el.className === '') {
                //el.parentNode.className = 'sub'
                el.className = 'sub';
            } else {
                //el.parentNode.className += 'sub'
                el.className += ' sub';   
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated my response to reflect changes in your original post

Comment: However, do you want the LI > UL (the UL itself) to get the class of 'sub', or do you want the LI > UL's parent (the LI) to get the class of 'sub'?